# How to open a specific access database with Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp xlMicrosoftAccess

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to use TransferSpreadsheet code to import an excel sheet in Access.

The code works if Access (and the table) is open. I would like to activate the Application directly from excel and import afterwards.

To open the application I have:

```
Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp xlMicrosoftAccess
```

This command opens the application, but I would need the open directly a specific Access database with the table I want to import into.

Comment: Consider using Access as a database and not an app and have Excel connect to it and append its data. Same process if inserting into Oracle, Postgres, SQLite, and other databases.

Comment: Thank you Parfait, I agree with you but I think I could use the "importExportSpreadsheet" macro in access and recall it through excel. The problem is that in the ImportExportSpreadsheet macro I can only select the range of cells, while I would like to select the range IN a specific tab of an excel file. So I have a spreadsheet with more sheets and select one with the data to import. Do you think is possible to select it maybe modifying the VBA converted code from access? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a As Access.Application   ' Add Access reference

Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp (xlMicrosoftAccess)
Set a = GetObject(, "Access.Application")
```

This code does what you have got to, but using the `getObject` gets an object of class name if supplied to an object, this case `a` of type `access.application`

Bear in mind that this is just the application opening, you will need to open the relevant database into the Access application, before proceeding also.